# ActiveSearch::EmptyTermError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im using the Active_Search plugin to try and add some simple search features to my app, it works OK when their it is found somethind in the DB but if i simply run a search with no input then it gives me the error message "ActiveSearch::EmptyTermError".

How do i make the search action return the correct values (which it can do), but also, if there is nothing found or nothing inputed the app tells me this using the flash.

Here is the code:

```
def search
  if params[:query]
    query = params[:query]
    @users = User.find_using_term(query)
  else #i.e nothing is found in the query so do this
    flash[:notice] = "No Results Found"
    redirect_to :action => "home"
  end
end
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the error using a `rescue` block:

```
def search
  @users = User.find_using_term params[:query]
rescue ActiveSearch::EmptyTermError
  flash[:notice] = "No Results Found"
  redirect_to :action => "home"
end
```

That way, though, if the search ran fine, but the result set is still empty, you won't be redirected. Here's some code that flashes and redirects you for both empty results and an EmptyTermError.

```
def search
  @users = User.find_using_term params[:query]
  return unless @users.empty?
rescue ActiveSearch::EmptyTermError
ensure
  flash[:notice] = "No Results Found"
  redirect_to :action => "home"
end
```

The `return` just leaves if we've got results.

The `rescue` block is empty, it just lets the error pass through.

And the `ensure` block runs whether we've handled an exception or not. (But certainly not if we returned before it.)

Answer (score -1):

There is a distinction between
   User.find()
      vs
   User.find_all()

The first one will throw an exception if no records are found.  The second one will return nil.   IN case of the first one it is like you are searching by 'primary key'.

May be related to your issue...

Comment: find_using_term is a method from the ActiveSearch plugin, it's not a dynamic finder.